# Get Application Updated Date on Android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app manager. It keep track of when an app was updated. Is there are way to find out the "Date when an application was last updated" on an Android Device. I want to get last Updated date for my android app.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to write an app wich finds out if its up to date or not?

Comment: I was developing an android app. I wanted to keep track the number of times any app was updated and last updated time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using `PackageManager`

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
long time = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).lastUpdateTime;
```

`packageName` - is your app package name